# Where can I find recorded mathematics lectures in Chinese?

Tags: data-request, education, video, academia

I'm learning Chinese, and in particular I'm interested in studying university-level mathematics in Chinese.  I study Chinese while making YouTube videos; the existence of a (largely imaginary) audience has two language-learning benefits: (a) I tend to pay more attention, thinking that someone is watching, and (b) I tend to recap for the audience what has been said, and give my own thoughts.

I found [this Chinese linear algebra course from MIT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgbjhzDndOY&list=PL751FDC0AD3A71B3E).  This is exactly what I'm after, but there's only 6 videos.  I'm hoping there's more videos like this, and ideally with a license like the MIT videos where it's unproblematic for me to make YouTube videos without copyright concerns.

**Question**: Where can I find recorded mathematics lectures in Chinese?

Searching the MIT website [like this](https://ocw.mit.edu/search/?q=%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6) didn't give me anything in Chinese.